# How do I add an anchor attribute to a route?

Tags: 8, routes

I've created a route:

```
regions.taxonomy_term.edit_form_header:
  path: '/taxonomy/term/{taxonomy_term}/edit'
  defaults:
    _entity_form: 'taxonomy_term.default'
    _title: 'Edit term'
  options:
    _admin_route: TRUE
  requirements:
    _entity_access: 'taxonomy_term.update'
    taxonomy_term: \d+
```

But now I can't add to path anchor attribute.

For example:

```
path: '/taxonomy/term/{taxonomy_term}/edit#header'
```

Comment: Why does it need to be defined in the route?

Comment: @Kevin Because it's route for contextual links, and I have two routes for one page with "field_group" tabs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks everyone!

I have solution my for problem.
You just had to add it to this **my_module.links.contextual.yml** file.

```
regions.taxonomy_term.edit_form_header:
  title: Edit this block
  group: region_taxonomy_term
  route_name: regions.taxonomy_term.edit_form_header
  weight: 10
  options:
    fragment: 'edit-group-header'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible because the anchor tag is never sent as part of the HTTP request by any browser, it is only interpreted locally within the browser.

> RFC 1808 Section 2.4.1 - "Note that the fragment identifier is not
>   considered part of the URL."